# How to release the camera in OpenCV (ubuntu-12.04)

Tags: c, opencv

How can I release the camera in OpenCV without closing the running program?
I used the following code but camera is still in on condition.

```
main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    int j;
    CvCapture* capture = NULL;
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );

    IplImage *frames = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    //Create a new window
    cvNamedWindow( "Recording ...press ESC to stop !", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    while(1)
    {
        if (j<10)
        {
            frames = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            cvShowImage( "Recording ...press ESC to stop !", frames );
        }
        j++;

        if(j==10)
        cvReleaseCapture ( &capture );

        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvDestroyWindow ( "Recording ...press ESC to stop !");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you compare `(j < 10)` and `(j == 10)` without first initializing `j`. This is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/1601291), which is a Very Bad Thing. In your case, it happens that the camera doesn't turn off.

The fix is simply to initialize `j` before you use it, like so:

```
int j = 0;
```

Comment: Aurelius thank you for answer but it didn't solve the problem. I have initialized the variable j, still the camera is on state. my aim is to use single camera for two separate processes. so I started with this code.